# When does cosine multiplied by hyperbolic cosine equals one?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

What are the possible ways to solve $\cos(\alpha)\cdot\cosh(\alpha)=1$? I'm trying to get to an equation to find the roots of $\alpha$ here.

Any guidance on how to get there is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many (real) solutions. To get an idea of their nature render the equation as $\cosh(\alpha)=\sec(\alpha)$ and graph both functions.  The secant function curves upwards more sharply than the hyperbolic cosine so that $\alpha=0$ is the only solution with absolute value less than ${3\pi}/2$.  But for larger absolute values of $\alpha$ other solutions come in pairs satisfying $(2n-1/2)\pi < \alpha < (2n+1/2)\pi$ for each nonzero integer $n$.  These nonzero solutions have no exact form in terms of elemmentary functions but are fairly easy to pinpoint numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth mentioning that existence of the infinitely many real solutions is just application of the Intermediate Value Theorem with careful bookkeeping. However, other than $0,$ there is no reason to expect a closed form for any of the other solutions. Numerical approximations, yes.

There are infinitely many solutions. The easy one is $0.$ At any odd multiple of $\pi/2,$ cosine is $0.$

Let's begin with $ 3\pi/2 \approx 4.7123.$  Then $\cosh \frac{3 \pi}{2} \approx 55.66338,$ reciprocal 0.017965. Evidently the nearby root is $4.730040745,$ just a little bigger than $3\pi/2.$

Next $5 \pi/2 \approx 7.85398.$ The nearby root is $7.853204624,$ just a little smaller than $5\pi/2.$

Next $7 \pi/2 \approx 10.99557429.$ The nearby root is $10.99560784,$ just a little bigger than $7\pi/2.$

I need to do more work to figure why there is no solution to $$\cos x \cosh x - 1 = 0$$ near $x = \pi/2.$ Actually, Oscar has pointed out thet the single solution at $0$ should be thought of as a double root. Good thinking. Meanwhile, 
$$ \cos x \;  \;  \cosh x  \; -1 \leq \; \frac{- x^4}{6} + \frac{ x^8}{2520} \; \; \; \mbox{for} \; \; \; |x| \leq 2.$$

I told it to divide the $y$ values by $50$ so it is possible to see more of the graph including the roots I mentioned up to 10.9956

[image]

[image]

Comment: You effectively have two roots in $(-\pi/2, +\pi/2)$ like every other interval with positive cosines, except they coalesce into one double root (at zero, of course).

Comment: Interesting problem, indeed ! I found an explicit solution in terms of Lambert. For the tenth root, the approximation gives more than 40 exact significant figures. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As said in answers and comments, beside the trivial $x=0$, the roots of the equation $$\cos(x)\cosh(x)=1$$ are close to $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2$ and, if $x$ is a root, $-x$ is also a root. So, let us just focus on the positive roots.

Since the first root is already large, we can make the approximation $\cosh(x)\approx \frac{e^x}2$. Moreover, around $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2$, by Taylor $$\cos(x)\sim (-1)^{k+1}\left(x-\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2\right)$$ So, for the $k^{\text{th}}$ root, the equation can be approximated as $$(-1)^{k+1}\left(x_k-\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2\right)\frac{e^{x_k}}2=1$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$x_k=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2+W\left( (-1)^{k+1}2 \exp\left(- \frac{(2k+1)\pi}2\right) \right)\tag1$$ For the first roots, this gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_k \\
 1 & 4.7300412 \\
 2 & 7.8532046 \\
 3 & 10.995608 \\
 4 & 14.137165 \\
 5 & 17.278760 \\
 6 & 20.420352 \\
 7 & 23.561945 \\
 8 & 26.703538 \\
 9 & 29.845130 \\
 10 & 32.986723
\end{array}
\right)$$ which, for $k>1$, are exact for more than eight significant figures.

In fact for large $k$, the solution given by $(1)$ can be again approximated as $$x_k=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2+ (-1)^{k+1}2 \exp\left(- \frac{(2k+1)\pi}2\right) \tag2$$